# Rest of the screen darken with center display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a image capture page. Currently i utilise javascript to utilise web cam and display on the page. But i wanted the whole screen to darken with the center div without the darken effect. I know for opacity, once applied, all the child will be affected.

So i was wondering if there are ways to create my desire look?

[image: Example]

Comment: You can take center div with transparent background with border.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a whole new overlay for your page, using Flexbox to center your div, darkening the spacers, like so:

```css
.container-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}

.container-inner {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  background-color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-outer">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="container-inner">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="content">
    
      <!-- CENTERED CONTENT HERE -->
      
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

You can even apply a `filter: blur;` effect to the `.spacer` class, if you are drawing this over your existing page. I would make the spacers transparent in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a overlay like:

```
.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div>
    Your content
  </div>
</div>
```